# Getting vk.com embed code automatically

Tags: php, vk

I want to automatically get vk.com embed code.  I've already figured out how to get part of it

```
http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=3145131&id=159485516&hash=d821df23b7dc0b54&hd=1
```

I've got the oid and id from the page source but the hash is being computed once i click on the video and what i want is that given a link like this `http://vk.com/video56612186` i want to get the embed codes of the videos in the folder.  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know what `vk.com` is, nor did I follow the link, but I'm assuming that `http://vk.com/video56612186` redirects to `http://vk.com/video_ext.php?<params>`.  You should be able to use cURL to read the `Location` header, and then get the redirected URL string.

Comment: no actually http://vk.com/video56612186 contains a list of videos.Once i click on the video a screen like a pop up appears to play the video.Changes in the script i noted is that a part of code is added at the bottom at the page when i click on one video.This is what i have to get but if i get the page by curl i get a list of videos with only thumbnails and not any reference to the video.Even if i get a reference to the video the hash changes for the embed code.

Comment: Does vk.com have an API?

Comment: Yes but i don't think it does have one for getting videos

Comment: necro-comment as I see, TS can use [video.get API-method](https://vk.com/dev/video.get)
and get needed link from the result object
**response->items[0]->player**